# Change Icon Of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable, android-navigation, android-actionbaractivity

I am having trouble with changing my navigation drawer icon to a custom one. I've currently had to implement the standard drawer icon which has 3 horizontal lines on top, but now I want to replace this with my custom drawer icon.

This is how my `mDrawerToggle` is at the moment:

```
mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
    mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.app_icon,
    R.string.drawer_open) {
        // My code
    };
```

Comment: Is the above how you are going about it currently?

Comment: yeh right @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh

Comment: try set homeAsUpIndicator() with icon.

Comment: @Harry i had tried that too...mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.app_icon);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the sample code taken from 
[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

**Activity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yar @Tarun jain i had done same thing ...what is my problem check that... i know constructor of mdrawertoogle

Comment: @Tufan Did u added the following code..                                                       `@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}`

Comment: i had override both the method ....look at my pics my icon is displayed but when i wanna change ..it dosent change

Comment: if i add R.String.drawer_close then it gives me error change construcitr or change ic_drawer to toolbar..any soln

Comment: Can u check the import whether it is using V4 support library or not

Comment: ...yeh it is imported from b4 library

Comment: Check if you have added dependencies in build.gradle file or not if you are  using Android Studio. In Eclipse check the android support library. You should not add both V4 and V7 library.

Comment: i had done it already ..i had accepted ur ans ..now give me upvote @tarun Tak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74935/discussion-between-tufan-and-tarun-tak).

Comment: This CTOR doesn't exist. Only similar thing is having DrawerArrowDrawable instead of the drawable resource

Comment: NOT WORKING NOW

Answer (score 40):

Use below code,it's working for V7 ActionBarDrawerToggle

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_custom_icon);
 mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
          mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     } else {
         mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: You can use the Drawable resource id for setting an image file as a Navigation Drawer Icon.                                                             Example: mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_navigation_home_icon);                                                                                                            Hence, no need of using the below code:                                          Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),   R.drawable.your_custom_icon, getActivity().getTheme());

Comment: This was the best option for me. Setting the icon explicitly, rather than letting Android figure out whether to show a menu icon or back icon, is a lot more consistent for my app.

Comment: Why doesn't the icon auto-resize. When I use a 512*512 icon, It takes up the entire ActionBar.

Answer (score 5):

This is main activity

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);


        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menuicon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this format for your `mDrawerToggle`:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.CUSTOM_ICON, // Navigation menu toggle icon
    R.string.DRAWER_OPEN, // Navigation drawer open description
    R.string.DRAWER_CLOSE // Navigation drawer close description
    )
```

Change your drawable and make sure it is the same name as the one in the code.

Comment: This CTOR doesn't exist. Only similar thing is having DrawerArrowDrawable instead of the drawable resource

Answer (score 0):

This is the main layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the main Activity

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.menuicon, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

finally at **R.drawable.menuicon**(you can give your image id) it will work.

Comment: whenever i want to change my icon with ur code it give me error of change app-icon to toolbar...can u tell me which file extension you used

Comment: for image i have used png image but any extension image will work

Comment: if i follow ur code @Allu it gives me error constructor is undefined

Comment: see this link i have followed this link it works for me just check total code once in this link if possible http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: if i follow ur code it gives me error no constructor match for mdrawertoogle

Comment: r u using actionbar or toolbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74925/discussion-between-allu-and-tufan).

Comment: see my solution in chat