# Badge notification over drawer toggle in toolbar - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I want to notify user about new unread message in the app which is accessible through navigation drawer. I was thinking about notification badge something similar Apple have but over drawer toggle in toolbar.

This is what I have now:
[image: This is what I have now]

This is what I want:
[image: This is what I want]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @stkent I was thinking of replacing the drawer icon with my own view but I'm not too happy about that. Is there any other option?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could maybe use the stock drawable as a base image in a solution based on e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558303/change-icon-of-navigation-drawer

Comment: Can u post the code of the Toolbar and how do you specify those icons ?

Comment: @VasilyKabunov [Android - How to add badge counter to hamburger navigation menu icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881131/android-how-to-add-badge-counter-to-hamburger-navigation-menu-icon)

Comment: @MikeM. Nice solution. I'd even pull this out into an open-source library :)

Comment: Thanks @MikeM., I couldn't google this answer, seems it might be the solution for my issue. Let me some time to check

Comment: did you follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881131/android-how-to-add-badge-counter-to-hamburger-navigation-menu-icon

Comment: Hi @MikeM., could you rewrite your comment as an answer with some details, I'll accept it

Comment: @Vasily Hmm, well, it would basically be a repeat of my other answer, or mainly just a link to it, both of which are frowned upon. If this question were posted today, I'd likely just close it as a duplicate, and possibly still will after the bounty ends (can't do it while a bounty is attached). Anyhoo, I'm not hurting for rep, and the bounty has worked as intended, inasmuch as the extra attention got an answer. If you like, you can award it to someone else, if you think that appropriate, or you can let it expire, as it's non-refundable anyway. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 19):

[image]

[image]

I found this really cool BadgeDrawable class on the internet and you can add badge count to any drawable using this class. Please follow below steps.

Step 1: add below class to your project first.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.TypedValue;


/**
 * Created by Admin on 2/25/2016.
 */
public class BadgeDrawable extends Drawable {

    private float mTextSize;
    private Paint mBadgePaint;
    private Paint mBadgePaint1;
    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private Rect mTxtRect = new Rect();

    private String mCount = "";
    private boolean mWillDraw = false;


    public BadgeDrawable(Context context) {
        mTextSize = dpToPx(context, 8); //text size
        mBadgePaint = new Paint();
        mBadgePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mBadgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBadgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBadgePaint1 = new Paint();
        mBadgePaint1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
        mBadgePaint1.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBadgePaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    }

    private float dpToPx(Context context, float value) {
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        return px;
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!mWillDraw) {
            return;
        }
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
        float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
        // Position the badge in the top-right quadrant of the icon.

  /*Using Math.max rather than Math.min */
//        float radius = ((Math.max(width, height) / 2)) / 2;
        float radius = width * 0.15f;
        float centerX = (width - radius - 1) +10;
        float centerY = radius -5;
        if(mCount.length() <= 2){
            // Draw badge circle.
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+9, mBadgePaint1);
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+7, mBadgePaint);
        }
        else{
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+10, mBadgePaint1);
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+8, mBadgePaint);
        }
        // Draw badge count text inside the circle.
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mCount, 0, mCount.length(), mTxtRect);
        float textHeight = mTxtRect.bottom - mTxtRect.top;
        float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
        if(mCount.length() > 2)
        canvas.drawText("99+", centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
        else
        canvas.drawText(mCount, centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
    }

    /*
     Sets the count (i.e notifications) to display.
      */
    public void setCount(String count) {
        mCount = count;
        // Only draw a badge if there are notifications.
        mWillDraw = !count.equalsIgnoreCase("0");
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Step 2: Now create a drawable (in my case it is ic_badge_drawable.xml). Then copy and paste below xml text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/ic_main_icon"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_burger"
        android:gravity="center" />


    <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
    <item android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_burger" />
</layer-list>
```

here you can pass any drawable for now, later we can pass any drawable to those. These are just like place holders.

Step 3: We have already setup everything. Now you can use below method to set badge count for any drawable.

```
 private Drawable setBadgeCount(Context context, int res, int badgeCount){
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_badge_drawable);
        Drawable mainIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, res);
        BadgeDrawable badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
        badge.setCount(String.valueOf(badgeCount));
        icon.mutate();
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_main_icon, mainIcon);

        return icon;
    }
```

Step 4: I used it as below to change my default burger icon.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(setBadgeCount(this,R.drawable.ic_burger, 3));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);   // enable overriding the default toolbar layout
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);// disable the default title element here (for centered title)
```

Answer (score 15):

[image]

I have used simple TextView inside android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout please check below complete code

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         initViews();
     }

     private void initViews() {
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         setUpToolbar();
     }

     private void setUpToolbar() {
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
         ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.navigation_drawericon);
         ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case android.R.id.home:
                 mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                 return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     private void updateCounter(int count) {
         ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_nav_drawer_count)).setText(count + "");
     }

     public void closeDrawer() {
         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
     }
  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/container_layout"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

container_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_nav_drawer_count"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_text_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="8dp"/>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/home_frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

home_menu.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_search"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:orderInCategory="101"
                android:title="Search"
                app:showAsAction="always"/>
        </menu>
```

menu_text_bg.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution works nice for one screen (honestly it was my first thought to go this way, and I even wrote the code similar to yours with the `textview` inside `toolbar`. But when I realized that I will need to rewrite the layout on each screen of the app, I started to look for more universal solution.

Comment: If your TextView slides underneath the toolbar like it happened for me, set an `android:elevation` value higher than the Toolbar's value to fix the drawing order.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I had to use a shape instead of a vector in the menu_text_bg.xml file

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/red"/>

    <size
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"/>
</shape>

Comment: Very simple and efficient technique

Answer (score 4):

I know its late but still.
if you are using android Side Navigation Menu as a starter then there would be a file name **app_bar_main.xml**
in this file you'll see some code like below except for the **TextView** this **TextView** is responsible for showing badge just initialize it in **MainActivity** where you are initializing your **Toolbar** and change its **visibility** according to your need (visible when count is positive else gone) right now as you can see its **visibility** is **gone**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.thumbsol.beakns.activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hamburger_count"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle_bacground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

and here is the code of **red_circle_bacground.xml** put it in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#f00" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp" />

  <size
    android:height="25dp"
    android:width="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: So easy and great solution!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from TDSoft, you can shorten the procedure even further by extending DrawerArrowDrawable.

Step 1: (Except for DrawerArrowDrable, basically Same as TDSoft's Badge class).

```
public class BadgeNavigationDrawable extends DrawerArrowDrawable{

private float mTextSize;
private Paint mBadgePaint;
private Paint mBadgePaint1;
private Paint mTextPaint;
private Rect mTxtRect = new Rect();

private String mCount = "";
private boolean mWillDraw = false;



/**
 * @param context used to get the configuration for the drawable from
 */
public BadgeNavigationDrawable(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));

    mTextSize = dpToPx(context, 8); //text size
    mBadgePaint = new Paint();
    mBadgePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mBadgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBadgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBadgePaint1 = new Paint();
    mBadgePaint1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
    mBadgePaint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBadgePaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    if (!mWillDraw) {
        return;
    }
    Rect bounds = getBounds();
    float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
    // Position the badge in the top-right quadrant of the icon.
/*Using Math.max rather than Math.min */
//  float radius = ((Math.max(width, height) / 2)) / 2;
    float radius = width * 0.15f;
    float centerX = (width - radius - 1) +10;
    float centerY = radius -5;
    if(mCount.length() <= 2){
        // Draw badge circle.
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+9, mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+7, mBadgePaint);
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+10, mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+8, mBadgePaint);
    }
    // Draw badge count text inside the circle.
    mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mCount, 0, mCount.length(), mTxtRect);
    float textHeight = mTxtRect.bottom - mTxtRect.top;
    float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
    if(mCount.length() > 2)
        canvas.drawText("99+", centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
    else
        canvas.drawText(mCount, centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
}

/*
 Sets the count (i.e notifications) to display.
  */
public void setCount(String count) {
    mCount = count;
    // Only draw a badge if there are notifications.
    mWillDraw = !count.equalsIgnoreCase("0");
    invalidateSelf();
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
}
private float dpToPx(Context context, float value) {
    Resources r = context.getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return px;
}
```

}

Step 2: That is all you need, if you need to update your navigation drawer icon, call - Your events are all all preserved.

```
BadgeNavigationDrawable drawerIcon = new BadgeNavigationDrawable(MainActivity.this);
drawerIcon.setCount(String.valueOf(count));

mDrawerToggle.setDrawerArrowDrawable(drawerIcon);
                    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score -1):

I achive this by adding a `TextView` to my main layout with targeting the toggle.
in my mainactivity.xml I added this

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_ham"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="9sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and for adding badge:

```
private  void addBadgeToHamburger(int badge){
    badge_ham.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String counter = Integer.toString(badge);
    String s =  "   " + counter + " ";
    SpannableString sColored = new SpannableString(s);

    sColored.setSpan(new RoundedBackgroundSpan(Color.RED, Color.WHITE), s.length() - 3, s.length(), 0);
    badge_ham.setText(sColored);
}
```

Comment: Was able to show the badge in Kitkat... but for Lollipop, strangely it gave NullPointerException when referencing the badge view, in your case 'badge_ham'. Did you face such?

Comment: -1 Incomplete answer. The `RoundedBackgroundSpan` is something we have to come up with? Found some similar implementation but nothing with the same constructor.

Comment: Rounded bg span is avilable in :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaychang0917/SimpleText/master/library/src/main/java/com/jaychang/st/RoundedBackgroundSpan.java