# Android- app crashes while adding a navigation drawer to a custom toolbar

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I've made a custom toolbar and its Right-To-Left. and it looks like this:

[image]

I want a navigation drawer appears when I click on the right side icon. But when I add the navigation drawer to app, it crashes. I've tried many things and also searched a lot, but it didn't work.
It'd be GREAT it someone would help me.

Here is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar.MainActivity"
  >

  <include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer">

   <!-- Main layout -->
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
android:text="Hello"/>

  </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Nav drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/header_drawer"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:entries="@array/pages" />
    </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**right_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="end"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header_drawer"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:entries="@array/pages" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public ListView listView;
    public String[] pages;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public ImageView menu_icon;
    public ImageView  back_arrow;
    public boolean mSlideState;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle _mDrawerTg;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        menu_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
        back_arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        drawerLayout =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
        pages =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pages);
        _mDrawerTg =new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                null, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                mSlideState=false;
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened (View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                mSlideState=true;
            }        };

       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,pages));

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(_mDrawerTg);
        _mDrawerTg.syncState();
        menu_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mSlideState){
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                }else{
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);                }            }        });    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        _mDrawerTg.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        _mDrawerTg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (_mDrawerTg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
**logcat:**

```
01-18 12:34:25.386 29949-29949/com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar  
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar, PID: 29949 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar/com.playpersia.mycustomizedtool   
 bar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
 method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on    a null object reference at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method   'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null   object reference at com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

**UPDATE 2**

now I have this toolbar when I click on the right side icon the drawer opens & closes,
[right side drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNskZ.png)

Comment: What do you mean by : **I've tried many things** how should we know these tries? :) Add your logcats also please.

Comment: @Rami I added the logcat

Comment: @LinX64 I added the logcat.  I meant at first I used the Navigation Drawer Template in android studio but it didn't work, I think it was because I'm using a custom toolbar. then I used fragment instead if activity but it cased more complications for me. then again I made a BaseActivity, wrote the drawer code in it and made the MainActivity extends from it. but it didn't work too.

Comment: Now, it's better somehow, that problem is in the `ListView` as you can see, since you are using `AppCompatActivity`, you can simply use NavgiationDrawer.that is what docs says.and onething, if you wanna set a custom icon for that, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29559002/4409113 better to use `NavigationDrawer` not with that listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.**NullPointerException**: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method   'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null   object reference at
>   com.playpersia.mycustomizedtoolbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)

In `onCreate` method, your `listView` object is null.

You need to add

`listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);`

before

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String (this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,pages));
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Change your `activity_main.xml` to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer">

        <!-- Main layout -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
                android:text="Hello"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- Nav drawer -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header_drawer"
                android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:entries="@array/pages" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK, how can I instantiate it? and I'm not using any fragments, does it make a problem?

Comment: @Hadis Check my update. Also there is no need for *onCreateView()* method, you can comment/remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's much better now.I Updated my question & code. Now how can I delete the left side icon make the right side one open & close the drawer?  you've been a great help so far.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, if you have another question/problem open a new thread, don't update the OP...to not confuse future users.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your `MainLayout` since you are using `DrawerLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Your contents, for example, CoordinatorLayout with material design -->

    <!-- And after main Contents, here you can use NavigationDrawer also -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And instead of commented code, use your contents.

**You did it in wrong way, Take a look:**

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a
>   DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout. Inside the
>   DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the
>   screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another
>   view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.
>
> For example, the following layout uses a DrawerLayout with two child
>   views: a FrameLayout to contain the main content (populated by a
>   Fragment at runtime), and a ListView for the navigation drawer.

**Example:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You may want to take a look at the **Material Design Guidelines** for this implementation of course:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html