# How can we change ActionBarDrawerToggle icon?

Tags: android, android-drawable, drawerlayout, actionbardrawertoggle

I'm new with Android and in my app, I am using `DrawerLayout`, it's 
ok and fine. But I want to change `ActionBarDrawerToggle` icon.

**How can we change it?**

I tried a lot but I could not able to achieve the desired result, please help me someone?

### xml:-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### activity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Icon Of Navigation Drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558303/change-icon-of-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add this line to your tool bar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToogle);
    mToogle.syncState();
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_your_image);
```

mToogle.syncState() will take care of actions(opening and closing the navigation drawer).

Comment: then how can i set action for this please elaborate ur answer with some code

Comment: I am glad i could help.

Comment: You took my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you must 3 steps:

1. add `actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`
2. add `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon);`
3. add OnClick to new Icon like below:

   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
               }
           });

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a few hours here's how I finally got it to work:

My implementation is using a `Toolbar` and `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Use these lines in `onCreate()` to set the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(getToolbarId());

      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
      if (ab != null)
      {
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
      }
}
```

Then you need to change the NavDrawer icon, you will do it with this code `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.my_icon);`. But you can't just call this from anywhere, you **need** to call it **after** syncing the DrawerToggle state.

So call it like so:

```
    drawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be the correct one :-P

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        drawerLayout = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout ,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.drawer_icon,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                "drawer_open",  /* "open drawer" description */
                "drawer_close"  /* "close drawer" description */
                )
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }
```

Comment: this line showing errors drawerLayout = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.drawer_icon,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                "drawer_open",  /* "open drawer" description */
                "drawer_close"  /* "close drawer" description */
                )